# How do I initialize an instance of one class within another (Im new sorry)

Tags: python, class, import, python-3.8, python-3.9

Okay I'm making a fake amusement park ride, I have a tram class that just has a max # of stops for the init paramater, and a move method that adds 1 to the current station. I now have a park class that SHOULD basically print this in a nice format, but I'm getting stuck since I need to initialize my tram within the park init method.

Tram class:

```
class Tram:
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
    
    station = 1
    def move(self):
        Tram.station += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return "The Tram is currently at station {} out of {}".format(Tram.station, self.m)
```

Now the Park class:

```
class Park:
    import Tram as Tram
    def __init__(self, m, lst):
        self.m = m
        self.lst = lst
        

    def __str__(self):
        print('------------------------------------------------------------')
        print(' Station                  Customer                   Tram   ')
        for i in range(self.m, 1, -1):
            for j in self.lst:

                print('    {}                        {}                    '.format(i))
```

It's not finished so ignore the str part, I just need help on how I can create an instance of a tram inside the park init, like so:

```
class Park:
    import Tram as Tram
    def __init__(self, m, lst):
        self.m = m
        self.lst = lst
        self.tram = Tram(self.m/m) <- SOMETHING LIKE THAT or:
        tram = Tram(self.m/m)
```

Please help, this seems like a really dumb question but I'd appreciate an explanation too, I'm kinda new to classes. Also here's my end goal.

```
>> P = Park.Park(3, [[1, 2], [3, 1]])
>> print(P)


------------------------------------------------------------
 Station                  Customer                   Tram   
------------------------------------------------------------
    3                        2                    
------------------------------------------------------------
    2                                             
------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        1                       *T*    
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: yes, `Tram(self.m/m)` is how you do it, the same as creating an instance anywhere else... did you try it? What difficulties exactly are you encountering?

Comment: when i do self.tram = Tram(self.m/m) I get undefined variable 'Tram'
same as when i do it the other way

Comment: Ah, because you are doing `import Tram as Tram` inside your class body, don't do that. Why are you doing that? Just do it at the top of the module (as is normal). In the future, *please post the errors you are getting*. Don't make people guess.

Comment: wow that really fixed it, thank you so much! and yeah ill make sure to post my errors in my initial post next time, thank you again